# How to use a button from a fragment in a expandableListAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistadapter

I have a issue with my android app :
I have a **fragment** which has a **expandableListAdapter** and a button to save.

My question is when I edit some information in one of the list of the `expandableListAdapter` how can I use the button save.

Because when I use it on the `fragment itself` I don't have the data edited on the `expandableListAdapter` and it seems that I can't use it in the `expandableListAdapter` itself.

Can you help me with this issue.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to call a method in you expandableListAdapter(to save the data), after the save button was tapped.

If it is so, than:

1. create a object variable of you ExpandableListAdapter in the corresponding Fragment and assing it.
2. create a method in ExpandableListAdapter, which should be called to save the data
3. in onClickListener() of the button, call the method on the ExpandableListAdapter object, which you have created in step 2.

Comment: I will try it I'm not sure a totally understand what you suggest but I will  try step by step

Comment: It's ok I did what you said and it's work thanks for your help